# Duplicate files when adding compiling with Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add Jackson to my Android Studio project I do it by adding it to dependencies in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3'
}
```

Gradle build runs fine, however when I want to run tests in Android Studio it gives me the following error:

```
Error:Gradle: duplicate files during packaging of APK .../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
```

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
>       File 1: .../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.3/a30ec6f59b6d31b2df06fa73925fda2fc7e84486/jackson-annotations-2.4.3.jar
>       File 2: .../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.3/a30ec6f59b6d31b2df06fa73925fda2fc7e84486/jackson-annotations-2.4.3.jar

I have tried invalidating caches in Android Studio, but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can exclude it adding this block to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked after adding exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' and exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

Comment: Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: Just that the same file LICENSE.txt is present in two or more different locations and gradle does not like it. It's a bug that should be corrected in the lastest version of gradle